# UWP SendToAsync from Socket results in AddressFamilyNotSupported

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous, udp, uwp

I am using the *Socket* class from UWP to send data via UDP to a specific device.

The problem is that after a few send forth and back, my *SocketAsyncEventArgs* for Sending gets stuck and in SocketError i got AddressFamilyNotSupported.

Initializing of the classes is done like this

```
m_Socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
m_Socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 51020));
m_SocketReceiveEventArgs = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
m_SocketReceiveEventArgs.Completed += SocketArgsReceived;
m_SocketReceiveEventArgs.SetBuffer(m_ReceivingBuffer, 0,m_ReceivingBuffer.Length);
m_SocketSendEventArgs = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
m_SocketSendEventArgs.Completed += SocketArgsSend;
```

While I send via (the condition for the loop is just for testing purpose) :

```
m_SocketSendEventArgs.SetBuffer(aunReqBuffer, 0,aunReqBuffer.Length);
m_Socket.SendToAsync(m_SocketSendEventArgs);

while (m_SocketSendEventArgs.BytesTransferred == 0)
{
    // AddressFamilyNotSupported happens here after a few packets have been send
}
```

And receive repeatedly in a seperate thread by accessing the socket and calling ReceiveFromAsync(), which works.

Any idea why it suddenly stops working? 
If you need more informations I will gladly help out.

**Update 08.03.2017**

I wrapped the sending method in a using-statement and now it works. Can anyone explain this to me though? Especially the weird SocketError i get. And in my memories i already tried it with .Dispose() manually, so iam confused what is different there.

```
using (var sendargs = new SocketAsyncEventArgs())
{
    sendargs.Completed += SocketArgsSend;
    sendargs.RemoteEndPoint = m_remoteIpEndPoint;
    sendargs.SetBuffer(aunReqBuffer, 0, aunReqBuffer.Length);
    m_Socket.SendToAsync(sendargs);
    while (sendargs.BytesTransferred == 0)
    {
        // TODO: SocketErrorHandling
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms832250.aspx)?  Did you enable the necessary capabilities for the uwp app?  I saw you didn't use the socket relative APIs for windows runtime, but use the .Net socket, could I know why?  By the way what is the specific device? Did you have conditions to change a device for testing?

Comment: The problem is that the network connection works for sending a few times forth and back. And i already executed the uwp test sucessfully with a synchronous read and write method. I dont understand the third question though. The device iam sending from is my laptop and the other device is a specific hardware device for testing purpose.

Comment: There actually are a few other differences despite the using - didd you try it without the using but with the other changes? Then you could minimize the problem...

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your `m_SocketReceiveEventArgs` is stored as a class member, and since you say that's done in initialization.

So, you are reusing the same `m_SocketReceiveEventArgs` for every send.

Please look at what the MS doc says about the parameter to be passed to the [SendToAsync(SocketAsyncEventArgs)](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.sendtoasync) method:

> The SocketAsyncEventArgs object to use for this asynchronous socket
> operation.

I read it this way: you should be passing a new `SocketAsyncEventArgs` argument for each new `SendToAsync` call.

I think this explains why putting it in a using code block makes that code work: it's actually using a new argument for each call that fixes the code.